# how to jump from one page to another page in bottle?

Tags: bottle

In bottle, how to jump form one url to another url in one page?

```
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8080/login.html')
```

I tried like above, but it's not been opened in one page! I want it to be redirect, but not raise 303 or 302 error!

Comment: Jinming, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do, or how this is related to Bottle.

Comment: it just like location of js,can redirect to another url!@
ron.rothman

Comment: Do you want an HTTP redirect?  Why not 303/302?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like maybe (?) you're looking for a way to redirect incoming HTTP requests.  You mention not wanting to return a 302 or 303 (why not, exactly?), so here's how you'd do it with a 301 ("Permanently Moved"):

```
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    bottle.redirect('/the/destination/page', 301)
```